# Redshift SQL Workbench doesnot show Object Explorer

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I am relatively new to Redshift but have used the SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS) to work with SQL Server.
Now I have a project with Redshift and am using the SQL Workbench to query the Redshift Cluster.
However I dont find an Object Explorer kind of window on the SQL Workbench interface. Is there such a window on the SQL workbench?

Also, how do i select the active Redshift database on the SQL Workbench?
Used to be pretty simple in SSMS(Select the active database from a drowp down option list), but i am lost when it comes to SQL Workbench?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but about using specific database tools.

Comment: Did you try `Tools -> Show Database Explorer`?

Comment: Btw: SQL Workbench comes with an extensive manual: it's worth reading:http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/  (it also explains how to open the DbExplorer: http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/dbexplorer.html)

Answer (score 3):

The comment above from @a_horse_with_no_name is correct. The tab you're trying to find is called "Database Explorer" and it can be opened `Tools -> Show Database Explorer`.

Credit goes to @a_horse_with_no_name for answering first.